# Adding items to the Adapter breaks onItemClickListener events

Tags: java, android, android-layout

After re-organizing a custom ListView and Adapter so that it took advantage of a ViewHolder class, the code initially seemed to work. However, when one scrolls down to the bottom and it adds more items to the list, list elements suddenly lose the ability to be clicked. This was not the case prior to using ViewHolder. The custom objects within the list elements function correctly.

the Adapters getView:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = View.inflate(this.context, R.layout.company_listing, null);
        Log.d(Cloud.DEBUG_TAG, "Inflating View...");    
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView, context);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.populateFrom(companies.get(position),logoDown);

    return convertView;
}
```

The ViewHolder:

```
class ViewHolder{

ImageView theLogo;
TextView textName;
ImageView webButton;
ImageView phoneButton;
ImageView favoriteButton;
Context context;
Company currentCompany;



public ViewHolder(View row, Context context){
    theLogo = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageLogo);
    textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textName);
    webButton = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageWeb);
    phoneButton = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imagePhone);
    favoriteButton = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageStar);

    theLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_pic);


    this.context = context;


}

public void setIcon(Bitmap icon)
{

    try {
        if(icon == null) {
            theLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_pic);
        } else {
            theLogo.setImageBitmap(icon);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {}

}

public void populateFrom(Company oneCompany,CachedLogoDownloader logos){

    currentCompany = oneCompany;

    Bitmap tIcon = logos.getLogo(this);

    try {
        if(tIcon == null) {
            theLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_pic);
        } else {
            theLogo.setImageBitmap(tIcon);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {}


    //create listener for favorite star icon thingy
    favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        //...code removed...
        }
    });

    //set company name
    textName.setText(currentCompany.getName());

    //resolve web button visibility
    if(!currentCompany.getWeb().equals("")) {
        webButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //...code removed...
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        webButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //resolve phone button visibility
    if(!currentCompany.getPhone().equals("")) {
        phoneButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        phoneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //...code removed...
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        phoneButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know where the Problem is:
You are instantiating your ViewHolder only if convertView == null. So the calls findViewById are referring to ListViewItems out of the screen. If you put your constructor Code into your `populateFrom` everything should be fine

Comment: Im not at my computer right now, but that wouldn't account for the fact that it works before new elements are added, would it? and the custom elements still work correctly as well. The favorite button works, and the icons still update. The list items just cannot be clicked.

Comment: Try to add logs to see if  setOnClickListener is set and inside if it is triggered. It might be the case that its something inside the onClick method goes wrong, since your code looks vaklid